# How to Handle POST requests in Twisted

Tags: html, python-3.x, post, twisted

I have a very simple twisted script where you can handle POST requests:

```
class FormPage(Resource):
    isLeaf = True
    def render_GET(self, request):
        return b"""<html><body><form method="POST"><input name="form-field" type="text" /></form></body></html>"""

    def render_POST(self, request):
        return '<html><body>You submitted: %s</body></html>' % (cgi.escape(request.args["form-field"][0]),)

factory = Site(FormPage())
reactor.listenTCP(80, factory)
reactor.run()
```

But whenever I run this and fill out the box, I get and error:

```
builtins.KeyError: 'form-field'
```

Could anybody tell me why this is? thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution using request.content.read()

```
def render_POST(self, request):
    return '<html><body>You submitted: %s</body></html>' % (request.content.read())
```

It might not be the best solution, but It worked for me. Please comment If you have a better solution, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution.  I got stuck here for a long time doing the "O'Reily Twisted" in Python3.  Here's what worked for me:

```
def render_POST(self, request):
    return_value = "<html><body>You submitted: %s </body></html>" % (cgi.escape(str(request.args[b"form-field"][0], 'utf-8')))
    return str.encode(return_value)
```

I guess the first reason I had trouble was that the form fields were that can be extracted in python code were in byte string.  Only after I checked the request args that I realized that.  I suppose in python2, it was regular string.