# How do I handle POST requests in Twisted?

Tags: linux, python-3.x, post, twisted

I'm trying to write a script where someone can type the name of a website into a box and my script will render the resources of that website. I'm not sure how to go about it, I'm thinking it would like something like this:

```
class FormPage(Resource):
    isLeaf = True
    def render_GET(self, request):
        return b"""<html><body><form method="POST"><input name="form-field" type="text"/><input type="submit" /></form></body></html>"""

    def render_POST(self, request):
        answer = request.content.read()[11:].decode()
        ReverseProxyResource(answer, 80, b'')

factory = Site(FormPage())
reactor.listenTCP(80, factory)
reactor.run()
```

This script just isn't working, when the script I get an Error: `Request did not return bytes`. Could anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong or where I can learn more about this subject? thanks!!

Comment: Please don't ask two times the same question.
[How to Handle POST requests in Twisted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37398611/how-to-handle-post-requests-in-twisted)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't worked with Resources and Site objects in a while, but I'm pretty sure you have overload the `Resource.getChild()` method and return a `ReverseProxyResource` to achieve what you want.  It can get a bit messy in my opinion if you go that route.  However, in `klein` what you're trying to do is trivial and can easily be solved.  You basically set `branch=True` and that makes it so that a `Resource` object can be returned.  For example:

```
from klein import Klein
from twisted.web.proxy import ReverseProxyResource

app = Klein()

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def render_GET(request):
    return b"""<html><body><form method="POST"><input name="form-field" type="text"/><input type="submit" /></form></body></html>"""

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def render_POST(request, branch=True):        # branch=True lets you return Resources
    answer = request.args.get(b'form-field', b'localhost').decode('utf-8')        # also use request.args instead
    return ReverseProxyResource(answer, 80, '')

app.run('localhost', 80)
```

Now for the final matter, you're running this on Python 3.x and it seems like `ReverseProxyResource` hasn't been fully ported over yet.  So if you run this code in Python 3, you will get tracebacks.